# Porque o tamanho da tela no navegador é diferente do real?

Tags: css, media-queries, resolução-de-tela

Eu sou péssimo quando se trata de design HTML + CSS, mas como programador web, muitas vezes me vejo tendo que fazê-lo.

Por muitas vezes tenho que fazer as tais *media-query* para ajustar o layout.

#### Questão

- Se eu tenho um celular com resolução 360x592, porque na hora de montar a *media-query* e resolução é 980x1413?
- Qual a relação para essa diferença?

Comment: Tens algum código que mostre isso na prática? Parece ter algo incorreto...

Comment: se pressionar F12 no google chrome, vai abrir o dev tools, pressione CTRL+SHIFT+M para abrir o modo device. teste à vontade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guilherme, 
certamente seu problema é causado pelo ***pixel ratio***, ele muda a visão dos pixels dependendo do dispositivo, aqui vai uma ótima dica para ti:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Logo, não só para dispositivos móveis, mas para *desktop* é importante notar que o Chrome faz uma análise diferente do Firefox para o tamanho da tela em sistemas operacionais diferentes, como por exemplo no Línux, onde o a barra lateral do Ubuntu é levada em consideração pelo Chrome, mas não pela raposinha!

Complementar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Poderia explicar um pouco como funciona este recurso? e porque isso ocorre?

Comment: Pesquisando sobre o que comentou, encontrei este [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) se quiser complementar a resposta.

Comment: Boa Guilherme, é isso mesmo que eu ia te explicar, o uso do viewport, scale e content, mas pelo link que tu achou já é uma boa ideia de como corrigir isso, eu acho

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece por causa do pixel ratio do seu dispositivo.
provavelmente você esta testando em um celular com pixel ratio 3, entao enquanto a tela é `360x592`, os pixels vão se comporta como `980x1413`

Na prática, para efeitos de construção de tela, existem 360x592 pixels. Mas cada um desses pixels, representa 3x3 pixels no dispositivo físico. Isso acontece em dispositivos de altíssima resolução, como Galaxy S4,HTC DROID DNA, etc.
Esses pixels sao usados para melhorias visuais, mas não estão disponíveis para o desenvolvedor, pois uma linha de 1 pixel real seria tao fina que não seria visível.

Mais em http://sergiolopes.org/resolucoes-dpi-pixel-ratio-retina/

Comment: Link muito interessante, poderia explicar um pouco em sua resposta?